# unable to get data from postgres using pg-promise and vue.js

Tags: javascript, postgresql, vue.js, feathersjs, pg-promise

I want to use pg_promise with feathersjs and vuejs to display results of query run on postgres db, my sql.js looks as follows

sql.js

```
const express = require('express');
const jsonexport = require('jsonexport');
const dbgeo = require('dbgeo');
const router = express.Router();
function dbGeoParse(data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dbgeo.parse(
      data,
      {
        outputFormat: 'geojson',
      },
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(result);
        }
      },
    );
  });
}

// expose sql endpoint, grab query as URL parameter and send it to the database
router.get('/sql', (req, res) => {
  const { app } = req;
  const sql = req.query.q;
  const format = req.query.format || 'topojson';
  console.log(`Executing SQL: ${sql}`, format); // eslint-disable-line

  // query using pg-promise
  app.db
    .any(sql)
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('data',data)
      // use dbgeo to convert WKB from PostGIS into topojson
          return dbGeoParse(data).then((geojson) => {
            res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=query.geojson');
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            return geojson;
          });
    })
    .then((data) => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // send the error message if the query didn't work
      const msg = err.message || err;
      console.log('ERROR:', msg); // eslint-disable-line
      res.send({
        error: msg,
      });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have configured my app.js to use sql.js as a route by adding following lines to it

```
const pgp = require('pg-promise')({
  query(e) {
    console.log(e.query); // eslint-disable-line
  },
});
const connectionString = 'postgres://abc:abc123@localhost:5678/gisdb';
// initialize database connection
const app = express(feathers());
app.db = pgp(connectionString);
app.use('/sql', require('sql'));
```

but when I call handleSubmit fuction shown below from my vue component

```
handleSubmit() {
    const SQL = "select * from spatial_search(searchmethod := 'id',sale_price :=10000,tax_ogcid := 
84678,distance := 0.5)";
    const queryType = 'sql';

    fetch(`/${queryType}?q=${encodeURIComponent(SQL)}`)
      .then(res => {console.log('res',res.json())})}
```

I get the following error

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

I think I might be doing something wrong here. Can someone help me?

Comment: the server is sending, most likely, HTML (common cause for such an error, the `<` is the clue) ... check the browser developer tools network tab to see what your server is sending as a response to this request - or, even easier ... `.then(res => res.text()).then(console.log)` to output exactly what the response is

Comment: its returning html of the main app, but I want to it return json from postgis db, can you let me know how to do this?

Comment: you'll need to debug your server code - or perhaps someone more familiar with it will coma along - I don't understand enough of your server code to help you debug it

Comment: You are logging the query method from within pg-promise, but your question does not include what it outputs. It really should ;)